# I am using DataFrameMapper to keep the column names whenever I use fit_transform, however all of the columns names concat into one big string

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline, data-cleaning, feature-selection

Here is the code I have...

```
from sklearn_pandas import DataFrameMapper
mapper=DataFrameMapper([
    (['MSSubClass', 'MSZoning'], PCA(1))
], df_out=True)
np.round(mapper.fit_transform(x.copy(), 2))
mapper.transformed_names_
```

Where x is a dataframe that looks like...[DataFrame screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nVZ1.png)

The problem I am running into is that mapper.transformed_names_ outputs

```
['MSSubClass_MSZoning']
```

Where the two string in the list become concatted.

I do not understand why the strings are being stuck together into one big string.